# Chinese password in masked text box in Windows Forms?

Tags: winforms, passwords, ime, maskedtextbox, chinese-locale

When a Windows Forms [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.TextBox(v=vs.110).aspx) is in password mode, it is restricted and the [ImeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.imemode(v=vs.110).aspx) is disabled (As discussed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) and [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/21a7f4ed-3589-43fb-b9dd-c30033e12358/chinese-input-on-textbox-with-password)). How can I design a textbox that doesn't reveal the user's input but that takes/collects the Chinese input from the keyboard (basically a workaround for taking in Chinese input in a password TextBox)?

Comment: Part of the answer can be found here:

[Masking windows form password][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246365/mask-password-string/30325385#30325385

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the OnKeyPress event to intercept input before it appears in the TextBox. Save the input somewhere else and put some masking char into the TextBox.

```
private void TextBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    //save the key pressed
    TextBox1.Text += "*";
    e.handled = true;
}
```